# Accessing a variable that's outside of a script

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, bootcamp

I have the following code but can't access 'myVariable' from within the script -- I assume because it's a function and 'myVariable' needs to be a global variable. How does one create a global variable?

**(Note: this is a .cshtml file in a ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    @{var myVariable = "this is what I want to access and change later in the script";}

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
  ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('[name="optradio1"]').on('change', function () {
        $('#accordion-second').slideToggle();
        $('#accordion-first').slideToggle();
        alert(myVariable);
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use data-attributes:

```
<script id="myScript" data-myvar="@myVariable">
    $('[name="optradio1"]').on('change', function () {
        $('#accordion-second').slideToggle();
        $('#accordion-first').slideToggle();
        alert($('#myScript').data('myvar'));
    });
</script>
```

Usually put on the HTML content tags because you normally have some unique identifier already or class, but you can do it on script tags as well.

Comment: Thanks @TimVermaelen! Is there a way to use data-attributes to set one variable equal to another? For example, if `data-myvar2=@myVariable2` was also included could I set one equal to the other inside the script? Because I like using the data attributes since they seem similar to passing in variables but am unsure how to set one equal to the other.

`$('#myScript').data('myvar') = $('#myScript').data('myvar2');` doesn't work...

Comment: Nevermind to the second question @TimVermaelen -- I was able to figure it out via the jquery API documentation. The following worked:

`$('#myScript').data('myvar', $('#myScript').data('myvar2'));`

Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Please change which is as `alert(myVariable);`

instead of using that please use the below code.

```
       var val = parseInt('@myVariable') + 5;
        alert(val);
```

Try this one.

Comment: if suppose i want to add some value with @myVariable then how can i achieve that? For example myVariable = myVariable + 5

Comment: If it is use full, just mark answer as correct by clicking the up arrow front of the 0, which is in left side of my code like menu.

Comment: thanks @Aravindan but this unfortunately didn't work for some reason -- additionally, my variable is a string as opposed to an integer. I tried `var val = toString('@myVariable');` instead and it returned **[object Window]** in the alert